# Does this work with DeleteAll in yii 2

Tags: yii, yii2

Does this syntax work for Yii 2 Delete all query?

```
Model::deleteAll('something is NULL && something2 is NULL');
```

Basically I want it to only delete the rows that match both something is null and something2 is null.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: It didn't work. I'm trying to figure out why.

Comment: Ideally it should. May be you can try: Model::deleteAll('something is NULL AND something2 is NULL'); Also is there any error you are getting while deleting?

Comment: I changed it to this and it worked Model::deleteAll(['AND', 'something is NULL', 'something is NULL']);

Comment: http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/delete-query/#deleteAll

Comment: Please try this solution for your problem : `Model::deleteAll('attribute_1 IS NULL AND attribute_2 IS NULL');`

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to solve this issue is to  first write one query that returns all the row with 'something is NULL && something2 is NULL' . Store all this row id in an array and then use the following code.

```
$model = Modelname::find()->where(['something' => null])->orWhere(['something2'=>null)->all();

$deletedIDs = [];

foreach($model as $model)
{
  array_push($deletedIDs,$model->id);
}

Modelname::deleteAll(['id' => $deletedIDs]);
```